# Prevent route interpretation when adding parameters to URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS application I have the following routing mechanism:

```
$routeProvider.when('/questions', 
                    route.resolve('questions', 
                                  'questions/', 
                                  'questions', 
                                  'overview', 
                                   access.authorizedAccess))
```

This works correctly, hitting a URL like `domain.com/app/#/questions` loading the correct controller and template.

What I want to do is have the option to add parameters to the current URL without triggering a page reload (basically reinterpreting the URL). The problem that I have now is that by doing `window.location.hash = '#/questions?query=test';` the route is reinterpreted causing a page reload.

What I have tried to do was this:

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
   if (next.indexOf('?') > -1)
     event.preventDefault();
});
```

This indeed does not trigger a route reinterpretation, but it removes the parameter from my hash, turning it back into `'/questions'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can your try the option `reloadOnSearch:false` during intitializing the routes in `$routeProvider`. See the documentation [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider)